# Convert/Cast float list to int list

Tags: ocaml

If I have a list:

```
[1.0;2.0;3.0;...]
```

Is it possible to convert or cast it into an integer list:

```
[1;2;3;...]
```

I have looked at the List library and can't seem to find a function for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `List.map` together with `int_of_float` to convert floats to integers.

Example:

```
let float_list = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] in
let int_list = List.map (fun x -> int_of_float x) float_list in
(* int_list is [1; 2; 3] *)
...
```

Answer (score 4):

```ml
utop # List.map;;
- : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

takes a function `f : 'a -> 'b`, that brings a value of type `'a` to a value of type `'b`, and returns a function from a list of `'a`s to a list of `'b`s:

```ml
utop # List.map int_of_float;;
- : float list -> int list = <fun>
```

In this case, `int_of_float : int -> float` is our `f`, so we get a function from a list of `float`s to a list of `int`s.

```ml
utop # List.map int_of_float [1.0;2.0;3.0];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```